# ¿Como se conecta un servidor de MySQL a Internet para ceso remoto en Ubuntu?

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu, vmware

Estoy realizando un proyecto y es la primera vez que trato de configurar una base de datos para uso remoto. Estoy usando actualmente el SO Ubuntu y Xampp. Me contacté con mi ISP y pedí que me abrieran los puertos 80 y 3306 para continuar, pero a este punto me he quedado estancado.

La necesidad que tengo es de conectar el servidor de base de datos a un programa java de escritorio que estoy desarrollando. El SO está corriendo en una maquina virtual (VMWare) y el programa lo desarrollo en mi escritorio de Windows 10.

Comment: Si tienes el programa y la BD en tu equipo, ¿por qué quieres accederlo mediante internet? ¿tienes siquiera una IP estática? Dejando aparte que abrir el MySQL a internet no suele ser buena idea.

Comment: ¿La BD esta dentro de tu equipo? o ¿Estas en una intranet y quieres conectarte al la BD? Si solamente estas experimentando te recomiendo algún servicio gratuito que te de esa BD publicada desde internet o contratar algún servicio de hosting.

Comment: @SJuan76 Quiero acceder a ella desde cualquier sitio que tenga acceso programa que estoy desarrollando. Ahora solo estoy realizando pruebas, pero mi plan es primero entender como funciona todo para realizar los ajustes en un equipo físico aparte.

Comment: @Draker Si, es correcto, por ahora son solo pruebas. Planeo a futuro cuando entienda como funciona hacerlo en un equipo distinto. Para acceder a ella desde cualquier equipo que posea el programa de escritorio.